# Cannot arrange layout with z-index

Tags: html, css, z-index

HTML

```
<div id='divTop'>divTop<br>divTop<br>divtop</div>
<div id='btnHome'>Home</div>
<div id="player">player<br>player<br>player</div>
```

CSS

```
body{
    position:relative;
    max-width:1024px;
    height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
}
#divTop{
    display:none;
    position:relative;
    z-index:5;
    text-align:center;
    background:#008080;
    border-bottom:medium ridge #D10000;
}
#btnHome{
    cursor:pointer;
    position:absolute;
    top:1.5vh;
    left:1vw;
    max-width:3.4vw;
    z-index:6;
}
#player{
    display:none;
    position:relative;
    z-index:3;
    max-width:95vmin;
    max-height:95vmin;
    border:medium ridge #ffffff;
    border-radius:9px;
}
```

JS

```
y = $(window).innerHeight() - $('#player').height();
$('#player').css ('margin-top', y/2);
$('#player').show();


$("#btnHome").click(function() {
    $('#divTop').slideToggle('slow');  
});
```

Why is `btnHome` inside `player`. It should be fixed on top-left of page ?

Clicking on `btnHome` why is `player` pushed down ? It should be also fixed. I just want to show-hide `divTop` by overlapping everything bellow.

fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2zAm5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `position:relative` from `body`.

**UPDATE:** add a parent wrapper to the `#divTop`

```
#wrapper {
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#divTop{
    position:relative;
    z-index:5;
    text-align:center;
    background:#008080;
    border-bottom:medium ridge #D10000;
}
```

JS

```
var dTHei = $('#divTop').outerHeight(); //get height of the #div top
$('#wrapper').height(dTHei); //set it as the height of the wrapper
$('#divTop').hide(); // hide the div top

//run your function here
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2zAm5/1/

Comment: Shivam, thanks, `btnHome` is fixed, but `player` is still movable ?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing position from relative to absolute

and use top,bottom,right and left instead.

Answer (score 1):

change positions of btnHome and player to fixed, and also use top property for player so it will not move: e.g. top : 200px.

```
#divTop{
    display:none;
    position:relative;
    z-index:5;
    text-align:center;
    background:#008080;
    border-bottom:medium ridge #D10000;
}
#btnHome{
    cursor:pointer;
    position:fixed;
    top:1.5vh;
    left:1vw;
    max-width:3.4vw;
    z-index:6;
}
#player{
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:3;
    max-width:95vmin;
    max-height:95vmin;
    border:medium ridge #ffffff;
    border-radius:9px;
    top:200px;  
 }
```